# Show Post Title and how many days ago it got published in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, count, archive

I want to customize my archive-list on my WordPress page so it displays something like this:

POST TITLE - 2 days ago
POST TITLE - 4 days ago
etc...

So far I only managed to display the post title with following code:

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'postbypost', 'limit' => 16) ); ?>
```

I have no idea how to move forward from this, any help?

Answer (score -1):

The function wp_get_archives calls the function get_archives_link to prepare the output.  The last step done in that function is to apply the filter by the same name as the function (i.e., get_archives_link).  So to modify as you desire, define your own filter function and add that filter in your functions.php file.

For example, the following code would add a class to the output of the function get_archives_link.

```
function example_get_archives_link($link_html) {
    if (is_day() || is_month() || is_year()) {
        if (is_day()) {
            $data = get_the_time('Y/m/d');
        } elseif (is_month()) {
            $data = get_the_time('Y/m');
        } elseif (is_year()) {
            $data = get_the_time('Y');
        }

        // Link to archive page
        $link = home_url($data);

        // Check if the link is in string
        $strpos = strpos($link_html, $link);

        // Add class if link has been found
        if ($strpos !== false) {
            $link_html = str_replace('<li>', '<li class="current-archive">', $link_html);
        }
    }

    return $link_html;
}
add_filter("get_archives_link", "example_get_archives_link");
```

You can find more info about the filter in the Codex.